# Code working in separate js file but not in ReactJs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms

I am using the following piece of code to get a value from a python script. It works perfectly when I run it as such in a separate file:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const process = spawn('python', ['src/components/BTC_NT.py']);

process.stdout.on('data', data => {
    test = data.toString();
});

process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('err results: %j', data.toString('utf8'))
});
process.stdout.on('end', function(){
    console.log(test);
});
```

But when I run it inside my React app like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Main = () => {
    const [Text, setText] = useState('');
    const [showPrice, setShowPrice] = useState('');
    const getVal = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        const process = spawn('python', ['src/components/BTC_NT.py']);

        process.stdout.on('data', data => {
            test = data.toString();
        });

        process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('err results: %j', data.toString('utf8'))
        });
        process.stdout.on('end', function(){
            console.log(test);
            setShowPrice(test);
        });
    }
    return(
        <div className="Main">
            <p>
                The following cryptocurrencies are available: Bitcoin(BTC), Ethereum(ETH). 
            </p>
            <form onSubmit={getVal}>
                <label htmlFor="CurrencyName">Currency Name: </label>
                <input type="text" className="CurrencyName" value={Text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
                <button style={{marginLeft:"5px"}} type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {showPrice !== '' && showPrice}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Main;
```

I get the error - "TypeError: spawn is not a function".

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Node-specific JS can't be used in browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running the file locally, you are apparently using some other runtime (probably node.js), when you run the file in react, you run it in browser, where things like `child_process` are missing